# How to printer image in usb flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to print images for POS printer that is not accessible with Usb. It can only be connected with USB cable. I found examples to print POS printer are connecting with usb. How can I make Flutter app to print image to specific printer that is Usb connected?

Comment: What operating system do you mean? Unix, Asterix or Panoramix?

Comment: Im use library flutter usb for Android and iOS